# Laravel dynamic scope only works first time

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm missing something with how the global scopes work in Laravel 5.5.

In my controller, `index` , I am passing filters into a getter:

```
public function index(SaleFilters $filters)
{
    return new SaleCollection($this->getSales($filters));
}
```

`getSales`:

```
protected function getSales(SaleFilters $filters)
{
    $sales = Sale::with('office')->filter($filters);

    return $sales->paginate(50);
}

protected function range($range)
{
    $dates = explode(" ", $range);
    if (count($dates) == 2) {
        $this->builder = Sale::with(['office', 'staff']) 
            ->where('sale_date', '>=', $dates[0])
            ->where('sale_date', '<', $dates[1])
            ->orderBy('sale_date', 'desc');

        return $this->builder;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have a scope setup in the `sale` model as such, which I would have thought would apply to the above filter automatically ?  If not, do I have to reapply the same scope, duplicating the scope code in the filter ?

```
protected static function boot() 
{
    parent::boot();

    $user = Auth::user();
    if (($user) && ($user['office_id'])) {
        return Sale::ofOffice($user['office_id'])->get();
    } 
}

public function scopeOfOffice($query, $office) 
{
    return $query->where('office_id', $office);
}
```

So basically, IF the user has an `office_id` applied, it should apply the `ofOffice` scope, therefore it should only ever return the sales that apply to that `office_id`.

Basically it works on page load via axios GET request

```
Route::get('/sales', 'SalesController@index')->middleware('auth:api');

axios
    .get('api/sales/?range=" + this.rangeFilter)
```

`rangeFilter` is basically a start and end date passed into the above filter query.

Can anyone shed some light on how the scopes really work or if anything is obvious as to why its not always working?  As I said, it works on page load where I provide default values for the `rangeFilter`, however when I change those days and it refetches via the same axios call, it seems to not be applying the scope, and I get ALL results instead of `where office_id = 'x'`

As far as i'm concerned, the range filter above would be executing on the first page load as well, so not sure why it would apply there, and not afterwards.

Comment: On first sight, it looks like you're mixing a local scope idea (`scopeOfOffice`) with a sort-of implementation of a global scope. Maybe it's worth trying to implement your scope as the documentation [states](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#global-scopes), so: the sope as a separate class, then the `addGlobalScope` method used in `boot`. You coud do the `Auth::user()` check in the global scope class directly.

Comment: Actually i implemented it as the doc states regarding "dynamic scopes"

Comment: Oh, I see, my bad.

Comment: Have you checked the values of your rangeFilter in every request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not mix the use of dynamic scope with global one. Also, static `boot` function does not expect a return. In order to use dynamic scope, you need to call it every time you need it. Hence, the name is dynamic. Query applied is not always executed by default. There so,

```
protected function getSales(SaleFilters $filters)
{
    $sales = Sale::ofOffice($anyOfficeHere)->with('office')->filter($filters);

    return $sales->paginate(50);
}
```

To suit your existing code, you may want to add an `if` statement in your model. Then call the scope function without argument.

```
public function scopeOfOffice($q) 
{
    if (($user = \Auth::user()) && ($office = $user->office_id)) {
       $q->where('office_id', $office);
    }
}

// Your controller
protected function getSales(SaleFilters $filters)
{
    $sales = Sale::ofOffice()->with('office')->filter($filters);

    return $sales->paginate(50);
}
```

---

If you feel so much cumbersome to type `ofOffice` repeatedly. A global scope is the way to go. Within your model static `boot` function, you can also apply anonymous function if you feel creating a separated class kinda bloat your apps.

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('officeOrWhatNot', function ($q) {
        if (($user = \Auth::user()) && ($office = $user->office_id)) {
            $q->where('office_id', $office);
        }
    });
}

// Your controller. No more `ofOffice`, it's automatically applied.
protected function getSales(SaleFilters $filters)
{
    $sales = Sale::with('office')->filter($filters);

    return $sales->paginate(50);
}
```

Comment: ah! this second option is what i'm after - I just couldn't make out how to pass in the office_id to the closure.  Will try it in a few hrs and mark your answer then, thanks!

Comment: brilliant, works!  What got me is having the `$office` received inside the `addGlobalScope`, so that it is available in the where clause